# HTTP Proxy Server in Python (with authentication)

Tags: python, http, proxy-server

I needed a simple HTTP proxy server written in Python so I began googling around and found this [page](http://proxies.xhaus.com/python/). Not all the proxies were working and so I settled for [this](http://code.google.com/p/python-proxy/source/browse/trunk/PythonProxy.py) or [this](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ProxyHTTPServer/).
..but neither of them support authentication. Has anyone come across a HTTP Proxy Server written in Python that supports authentication?

Thanks.

Comment: proxy.py supports basic authentication https://github.com/abhinavsingh/proxy.py

Answer (score 1):

> Useful for NTLM based authentication
>   on windows

- http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/

> Sortable comparison of open source
>   proxies in Python

- http://proxies.xhaus.com/python/